# hdd encryption before or after usage?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

I am reinstalling my system with win8.1 and archlinux dualboot.

I was wondering at what point i should encrypt the entire hdd with truecrypt.

Can i just encrypt the whole hdd any time i like, for example after i used (installed and used all programs i wanted) the hdd for a month?

Or is there a timeframe that i should act to securly encrypt the data, for example immediately after i installed both OS? (or even before)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq), Truecrypt allows you to encrypt NTFS formatted (system) partitions in place at any point (see below). Afterwards it will wipe the remaining free space (unless you tell it otherwise), so there's no known way to restore any (useful bits of) unencrypted data, that might have been there previously.

---

> **Can I encrypt a partition/drive without losing the data currently
>   stored on it?**
>
> Yes, but the following conditions must be met:
>
> - If you want to encrypt an entire system drive (which may contain multiple partitions) or a system partition (in other words, if you
>     want to encrypt a drive or partition where Windows is installed), you
>     can do so provided that you use TrueCrypt 5.0 or later and that you
>     use Windows XP or a later version of Windows (such as Windows 7)
>     (select 'System' > 'Encrypt System Partition/Drive' and then follow
>     the instructions in the wizard).
> - If you want to encrypt a non-system partition in place, you can do so provided that it contains an NTFS filesystem, that you use
>     TrueCrypt 6.1 or later, and that you use Windows Vista or a later
>     version of Windows (for example, Windows 7) (click 'Create Volume' >
>     'Encrypt a non-system partition' > 'Standard volume' > 'Select Device' > 'Encrypt partition in place' and then follow the instructions in the wizard).